# Minor revision: I haven't deleted the original file

Tags: publications, peer-review

I submitted an article to an emerald journal a month ago and 4 days back, I received a decision mail stating this, 'The reviewer(s) have recommended publication, but also suggest some minor revisions to your manuscript.  Therefore, I invite you to respond to the reviewer(s)' comments and revise your manuscript.

So the comment I got is the following, 'Comments to the Author: Please state the direction for future research related to these findings.'

I wasn't asked to change anything in the manuscript but just was asked to state directions for future research, which I haven't added before. Since this is a 1-hour task, I submitted it the very following day. How ever, while submitting the revision, I haven't deleted the original accepted manuscript. In the mail, I was asked to delete redundant files, but in the mail, it was not mentioned originally accepted manuscript was a redundant file. So I assumed that the revised file should be also submitted along with the original file. I have followed all the instructions given in the mail, but haven't deleted the original file. Today I mailed the editor stating my misunderstanding and asked him whether I can delete the original manuscript now. Will this be an issue? If so how serious it is?

Also, anyone having previous experience, kindly explain what does it mean, 'The reviewer(s) have recommended publication, but also suggest some minor revisions to your manuscript'. Does this mean after the minor revision, it will be mostly accepted?

Comment: You're fine, I suggest you take a break and relax a bit, you're overthinking things.

Comment: Well, I am a first-year research student and this is just my second journal. So obviously will overthink :) Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, purely procedural things like this are no big deal.  Try to do them right the first time, but if mistakes are made, it is not worth going to a lot of trouble to try to comply with the exact rules.

It helps to think through why such rules exist and the likely consequences of accidentally breaking them.  In this case, presumably the direction to omit the original manuscript is to slightly reduce the amount of work for the editor, by reducing the number of files to sort through and avoiding the need to double check which is the revised file.  Having the extra file there is a minor annoyance, but is not likely to cost the editor more than a few extra seconds of time.  And to be clear, there is no conceivable way that it would affect the fate of your paper, so you need not worry about that.

On the other hand, responding to your request to modify the submission will likely take the editor substantially *more* time than that, and so your request is counter-productive for everyone.

At most, if you really felt there was a risk of confusion as to which file was which, you could contact the editor and simply say "I accidentally submitted the original manuscript in addition to the revised one.  The revised one is [identify which file].  Sorry for any inconvenience."  This doesn't require any response from the editor, and so takes up very little of their time.

---

Your last sentence is a separate question; in general, please ask only one question per post.  However, yes, this is a clear sign that the journal intends to accept the paper, assuming the revision is made satisfactorily.